# Java Console Logger Exception Handling

Tags: java, console

I tried to block every exception message in my java application console and now I just don't how to do it.

I tried to use java.util.logging.Logger and i was added to him Handler which works good, but that Handler don't have function like "cancelPublish".

Is there any class in java with method which is executed before sending log and have as parameter Exception Object, and in which I can to stop "print" log to console, or replace him to my String?

I wanna send all my exceptions(like this lower) to cloud, and exception log replace with something like "Error ID:XX".

[image]

Next I need get Exception Object and send to database: Exception Name, Exception Message if exist, and excpetion trace.

```
getLogger().addHandler(new SH());

private class SH extends StreamHandler {

    @Override
    public synchronized void publish(LogRecord record) {

        if (record.getLevel().intValue() > Level.INFO.intValue()) {
            // I can there send that log to database
        }
    }
}
```

I tried something like this upper, but not every log with level WARN, or ERROR is exception, is there in java method like?:

```
getLogger().addExceptionListener(new ExceptionListener() {
        public void onCheck(ExceptionEvent e) {
            //First method which I want
            e.getException();

            //and second
            e.cancelPublish();
        }
    });
```

Is there something close to that in java?

Comment: you need to show what you have tried so far.  Please see [How to Ask a Good Question](/help/how-to-ask) and [mcve]

Comment: I added image if that helps.

Comment: Do you have any code to show us? Additionally you might wanna look into observer or subscriber pattern and add layer around the Logger and have code that you use to analyze and cancel or log.

Comment: I added some code examples.

Answer (score 0):

I relsolved it by adding Filter to my Logger:

```
    getLogger().setFilter(new Filter() {
        @Override
        public boolean isLoggable(LogRecord record) {
            //There I do what I want...
            return record.getThrown() != null;
        }
    });
```